# Angular-xeditable - Editable Row - Change Value

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I try to set a value of a select control to null when a checkbox is unchecked.

I try with onbeforesave and onaftersave but i want to do it dynamicly , so i used e-ng-change. I want also to not change the value if i cancel my changes but i can't access to the control value.

You can see the code here : http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/2833/

In normal forms, i set the value like this but here i don't have any know access

```
sco.editableForm.name.$setViewValue("1234")
```

Regards,

Marc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution of my problem to set value in editable mode :

sco.rowform.$editables[2].scope.$data = null;

Comment: Can I have support for this ? Thanks.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35556698/angular-xeditable-drop-down-e-ng-change-is-not-working